# How to change timezone in Selenium?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, time

I want to run Selenium on Firefox in multiple threads on Windows (so i can't just change timezone in system). I tried do it with [TimeShift.js](https://github.com/plaa/TimeShift-js), but after refresh page all data is lost.
I'm using python.

Comment: You'll need to provide some more detail here.  If you can't change the system time zone, then where are you trying to change it?  in the browser?  Please show us the code that you are using to try to do this.  Do you get any errors reported when you run your code and see "all data is lost"?

Comment: @breaks-software, i mean i want to change timezone only for one selenium window, no matter way